# Required Property and JSON PropertyName

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a class with an required attribute and a mapped JSON name like the following:

```
class MyClass {
  [Required]
  public string Foo {get; set;}
}
```

This works all fine. But combining this with an JSON annotation like the following, breaks the validation

```
class MyClass {
  [Required]
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bar")]
  public string Foo {get; set;}
}
```

Why does the behavior change here and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bar", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```